# calling setState method with other statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that calling setState method means I don’t have to manually invoke the ReactDOM.render method. Below is some example code:

```
...
render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>  
               Click
            </button>
        )
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 }, () => this.setState({ hasButtonBeenClicked: this.state.counter > 0 }));
        this.props.callback();
    }
```

since there is another statement `this.props.callback();` below the `this.setState()` method, so does ReactDOM.render method get called before or after `this.props.callback();`?

Comment: `setState` is not a replacement of `ReactDOM.render`. It's more `this.state = newState; this.forceUpdate()`. That is it does two things: updates component state and updates DOM associated with the component.

Answer (score 4):

> since there is another statement `this.props.callback();` below the `this.setState()` method, so does `ReactDOM.render` method get called before or after `this.props.callback();`?

After, in your case. The state update and call to `render` is asynchronous if `setState` is called within a React event handler (and may be asynchronous even if not, [more here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14422)). The sequence (within a React event handler) is:

1. You call `setState` with the state update.
2. You call `this.props.callback();`
3. React processes the state update (possibly combining it with other pending updates).
4. *(Some handwaving here about `shouldComponentUpdate`.)*
5. React calls `render` to have it render the current state.

If you want `this.props.callback();` called after the new state has been rendered, put it in a function as the second argument of `setState`:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(
        { counter: this.state.counter + 1 },
        () => {
            this.props.callback();
        }
    );
}
```

or

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(
        { counter: this.state.counter + 1 },
        this.props.callback
    );
}
```

...if `this.props.callback` doesn't care what `this` you call it with.

More here:

- [*State Updates May Be Asynchronous*](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) *(that title drives me nuts, because it's not that they **may be** asynchronous, it's that they **are** asynchronous)*
- [*`setState` API docs*](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: I voted this answer up, as it provides a better explanation than mine.

Comment: @CullenBond - Thanks. Your comment on your answer that it wasn't guaranteed finally broke the camel's back for me and I went to report a bug in the documentation that "may be asynchronous" should be "**is** asynchronous." Doing my due diligence with previous issues raised on this, I found that outside a React handler, it isn't guaranteed (link in the answer above). Thank you for that! V. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at my example of your code, this.props.callback() gets called immediately after the state has been updated.

```
handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1, hasButtonBeenClicked: true }, () => this.props.callback() );
    }
```

You have chained setStates, which seem unnecessary for readability. These should be grouped into a single setState call automatically, however one is nested into the callback and this would trigger multiple re-renders.. depending on ShouldComponentUpdate.

To avoid guessing or leaving it susceptible to future React updates:
Using the setState callback for this.props.callback, is the best way to ensure it is executed after setState completes.

Updated, based on T.J Crowders feedback and research with event handlers:
The way your code was structured it is most probable that this.props.callback will be called prior to the setState actually completing state updates, it will trigger the re-render once state updates.

-Because, it is in an asynchronous call and within a React event handler. SetState should update state after.(I am still no expert on promises, and have to wonder if there is a chance state could update within the millisecond, depending on your browsers internal clock and the batch processing)

For clarity, to others. This example is asynchronous and that means the code continues to be executed, while waiting for resolution. While setState returns a promise. In this case, it should absolutely continue to process this.props.callback(), until the promise is resolved.

Comment: The this.props.callback() may be called prior to the actual state update occurring. So as to be flawed, if a person thought state updated first and then this.props.callback would operate using new state.

Comment: @CullenBond Not "may be". It _is_ called prior to state update occuring. Re-read what T.J. wrote, he's already said that.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed that this.props.callback gets called before the state update, so is the terminology of async. It will happen when it happens.

Comment: It is not guaranteed, @PatrickRoberts... The structure of the code can ensure that it is performed in the intended order.
I have read T.J. Crowders well-written post. I have also used the sample code from the ReactJS.org link. It is possible that state updates first sometimes. Not my opinion.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Actually, there are times `setState` is synchronous (for now): https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14422 [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/oqw9vj8t/2/). The word from the React team Is "don't rely on that, not least because concurrent mode will likely change it."

Comment: *"The way your code was structured it is most likely that this.props.callback will be called prior to the setState actually completing state updates."* According to the React team, it's guaranteed in this case, because it's in a React event handler. Thanks to you, TIL that it's not guaranteed otherwise, prior to v17's concurrent mode. Thanks!

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder - While setState returns a promise..(in this case) Is there an infinitesimal chance that the promise could be resolved prior to this.props.callback()?